# Android app for generating PDF from images

Tags: gratis, android, pdf, images

I want an Android app that can import images from gallery and generate PDF.

I tried Docufy and camscanner.com app, both lack the ability to rearrange images in the right order once they are imported which is a must have feature. I can't generate a PDF that with wrongfully sorted images.

Other requirements:

1. It must be free.
2. Autocrop and crop
3. An image image per image color editing like Docufy.
4. Ability to rename files
5. Sync to Dropbox

Basically all the features found in Docufy or camscanner plus the ability to rearrange images.

Comment: the image quality produced by the app given in the answer is a bad i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once tried an app called image to pdf converter by bg studio i was able to arrange the images easily.
Here is a how-to with a link to the app http://www.howtogeek.com/249200/how-to-combine-multiple-images-into-a-pdf-file-on-android/amp/

Comment: Lacking features. Needs autocrop and crop, an image image per image color editing like docoufy. Ability to rename files and to sync on dropbox etc. And it has a low rating and users claims that it keeps crashing and has so many bugs

Comment: Having said that, I installed it and used it and it worked, therefore  I'll accept your answer and I upvoted it, but if another user gave me a better app that has the features listed above, which are available in docufy and cam scanner, I will have no choice but to accept his answer. Thanks for your answer Sir.

Comment: Glad it worked.I suggest you add these features to the original post because not everybody read these sub comments.

Comment: okay, will do :)

Comment: You shouldn't have a link-only answer as per the guidelines…

Comment: @wb9688 I am new here so i didn't know about that when i posted this answer but i noticed this in other questions so I'll take care about that in my answers in the future.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Docufy yesterday and they seem to have added this feature, called "reorder"

[image]

Comment: they've either added it or not. what do you mean by seem to have added?

Comment: @アレックス they added it